# Sum of sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n^3+n}{4n^5+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the following sequence for which I want to find if its convergent and if it is, find its sum.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n^3+n}{4n^5+1}$$
I can see that it is convergent by the limit comparison test using the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.
$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{2n^3+n}{4n^5+1}\cdot n^2\right]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[ \frac{2n^5+n^3}{4n^5+1} \right]=\frac{1}{2}>0$$
So, the sequence converges by the limit test because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is a $p$-series with $p=2$. However, I'm not sure how to go about finding the exact sum. Any tips?

Comment: [Not pretty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=sum%28%282*n%5E3%2Bn%29%2F%284*n%5E5%2B1%29%2Cn%3D1..infinity%29).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I saw that and was wondering if there was a nicer expression for it, but maybe there is not

Comment: As you say, the expression is not pretty. 

For a rude estimation you can just say

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2n^3 + n}{4n^5+1} \sim \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n =1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Real series: converges to $0.941187(...)$

Comparison: converges to $0.822467$

Comment: A slightly prettier form is Maple's: $$\frac{1}{5}\sum_\alpha (2 \alpha^4 + \alpha^2) \Psi(1-\alpha) $$ where the sum is over the roots of $4 z^5 + 1$.

Comment: To get this, expand $(2 n^3 + n)$ in partial fractions as $$ -\frac{1}{5} \sum_\alpha \frac{2 \alpha^4 + \alpha^2}{n - \alpha}$$
and use the fact that $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n-\alpha} = \ln(N) - \Psi(1-\alpha) + O(1/N)$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael I assume $\Psi$ is the digamma function.

Comment: @Gary Yes it is

Comment: Oops, I meant expand $(2n^3+n)/(4n^5+1)$ of course.

Comment: Equivalent to $$ \frac{1}{4} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k \: (2 \cdot \zeta (5 k+2)+\zeta (5 k+4)) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2n^3 + n}{4n^5+1} \sim \frac{159}{215}+\sum_{n = 3}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2n^3 + n}{4n^5+0}=\frac{159}{215}+\frac{-2565+240 \pi ^2+8 \pi ^4}{2880}=0.941958$$
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2n^3 + n}{4n^5+1} \sim \frac{166962}{209195}+\sum_{n = 4}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2n^3 + n}{4n^5+0}=\frac{166962}{209195}+\frac{-24605+2160 \pi ^2+72 \pi ^4}{25920}=0.941897$$

For the fun
$$\frac 1{4n^5+\epsilon}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\, 4^{-(k+1)}\,n^{-5(k+1)} \,\epsilon^k$$Makes the first line (with $\epsilon=1$)
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2n^3 + n}{4n^5+1} \sim \frac{159}{215}+\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (-1)^k 2^{-7 k-6} \left(2^{5 k+4} (2 \zeta (5 k+2)+\zeta (5
   k+4)-3)-9\right)$$ which converges very fast (alternating series and, if $a_k$ is the summand, the limit of $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ is $\frac{1}{972}$.

Computing the summation up to $k=6$ gives $\color{red}{0.9418872382347396661148}808$ to be compared to the "exact"                   $\color{red}{0.9418872382347396661148094}$$